# E-Mail rule to move Mails to a specific address into folder

Tags: exchange-server-2013

we've got a Exchange 2013 postbox with several E-Mail addresses assigned.
For better organization, Exchange should move incoming mail into various folders.
The target-folder depends on the SMTP-Address to which the mail was sent to.

Problem is: Exchange 2013 recognizes only the postbox itself as receipient and does not distinct between the different TO-addresses. How can a serverside-rule be made which respects TO?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Moving messages to a folder is a mailbox server side rule. You could log into the mailbox via OWA or Outlook and set up this rule.

Exchange will deliver mail to the recipient, its upto the recipient via rules what they want to do with it from there.